# Bes way to update the live Vue JS + Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am learning Vue JS 3. Now, I am developer a application using Laravel 9 with Vue js 3. Now, every time when I do some update I have to run this command:

```
npm run prod
```

And then have to make the entire project file as **compressed** zip file and then I upload the full **compressed** zip file to my server.

Note: I am updating every changes to by **git repo** .

So, my question is

1. whats the best way to upload the live laravel + vue js applicatoin?
2. If I only upload the app.js will it be work?

Thank You.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense without project setup being explained

Comment: @EstusFlask You didn't understand my question. I just want to know the correct way to everytime update my vue + laravel app to live server.

Comment: There's no universal "correct way". It depends on how things are done in your case. It's unknown what `npm run prod` does. You describe the problem like other users are already aware of your project, but they aren't. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: I don't want to ague with you but I simply and clearly asked my question.

Comment: If you're unable to answer it yourself, you can't be sure that you asked it correctly. You actually didn't, it's too unspecific and can't get a precise and correct answer in its current form